# Calculate movement from accelerometer every second

Tags: java, algorithm, accelerometer, sensors

I am trying to follow an example of how to calculate movement from accelerometer data. What I want to do is implement the [following algorithm](https://support.empatica.com/hc/en-us/articles/202028739-How-is-the-acceleration-data-formatted-in-Empatica-Connect-) in Java:

> Each second (32 samples) the acceleration data is summarized using he following method:
>
> **sum+= max3(abs(buffX[i] - prevX), abs(buffY[i] - prevY), abs(buffZ[i] - prevZ));**
>
> The output is then filtered:
>
> **avg=avg*0.9+(sum/32)*0.1;**

I am not so familiar with this kind of work, so I have some questions on how to translate the written algorithm into Java code. See my attempt at solving this:

```
calculateMovementG = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (isRecording) {

            double sum = 0.0;

            for (int i = 1; i < accelRawValues.size(); i++) {
                sum += Math.abs(accelRawValues.get(i).getX() - accelRawValues.get(i - 1).getX());
                sum += Math.abs(accelRawValues.get(i).getY() - accelRawValues.get(i - 1).getY());
                sum += Math.abs(accelRawValues.get(i).getZ() - accelRawValues.get(i - 1).getZ());
            }

            double result = 0.0;
            result = result * 0.9 + (sum/accelRawValues.size() - 1) * 0.1;

            if(result > 3.0) movementData.add(new GsrConverted(result, accelRawValues.get(0).getTimestamp()));

            accelRawValues.clear();

            //repeat every second
            accelHandler.postDelayed(calculateMovementG, 1000);

        } else Log.i(TAG, "isRecording flag false, stopping thread.");
    }
};
```

The lowest value I've gotten from this algorithm is something like `0.08`, while I can get very high values up to `13.50` if I shake my hand vigorously. Accelerometer is attached at wrist.

When using the official software I get between -2.0 and 2.0 as the documentation shows. How can I adapt the documented algorithm (link at top of this question) to achieve values in this range?

I am unclear on what is meant by "`max3`", and the commas between the different `abs` in the first line of the algorithm. I interpreted `abs` as `Math.abs`. I've initialized the counter `i` at *1* so as not to get a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Thank you for any help through comments and answers!

Comment: Surely `max3` is just the max of those three things, no?

Comment: So put each of those three statements in three lists iteratively, sort by value, summarize [0], [1], [2] of each list and then all nine top values?

Comment: If you only have three things, putting them in a list and sorting them is overkill.  A couple calls to `Math.max` should be enough.

Comment: But there are 32 values of each X, Y and Z. Math.max is a comparison between two values? Do you have an idea of what the comma signifies?

Comment: max3(abs(buffX[i] - prevX), abs(buffY[i] - prevY), abs(buffZ[i] - prevZ)) is just  Math.max(Math.max(abs(buffX[i] - prevX), abs(buffY[i] - prevY)), abs(buffZ[i] - prevZ))

Comment: Edit: Great, thank you, I will try that!

Answer (score 0):

- max3(abs(buffX[i] - prevX), abs(buffY[i] - prevY), abs(buffZ[i] - prevZ)) is just max(max(abs(buffX[i] - prevX), abs(buffY[i] - prevY)), abs(buffZ[i] - prevZ)).
- in `double result = 0.0;
          result = result * 0.9 + (sum/accelRawValues.size() - 1) * 0.1;`
  you set result to 0.0 so result * 0.9 is always going to be 0 it doesn't clearly say in the algorithm but i think result should be the result from the previous iteration (but I'm not sure).
  and with `(sum/accelRawValues.size() - 1)` I  think it should be
  `(sum/ (accelRawValues.size() - 1) )` because it's not the same thing.

try this

```
calculateMovementG = new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    if (isRecording) {

        double sum = 0.0;

        for (int i = 1; i < accelRawValues.size(); i++) {
            int absX = Math.abs(accelRawValues.get(i).getX() - accelRawValues.get(i - 1).getX());
            int absY = Math.abs(accelRawValues.get(i).getY() - accelRawValues.get(i - 1).getY());
            int absZ = Math.abs(accelRawValues.get(i).getZ() - accelRawValues.get(i - 1).getZ());
            sum += Math.max(Math.max(absX, absY), absZ)
        }

        double result = // get the result of the previous iteration
        result = result * 0.9 + (sum/ (accelRawValues.size() - 1)) * 0.1;

        if(result > 3.0) movementData.add(new GsrConverted(result, accelRawValues.get(0).getTimestamp()));

        accelRawValues.clear();

        //repeat every second
        accelHandler.postDelayed(calculateMovementG, 1000);

    } else Log.i(TAG, "isRecording flag false, stopping thread.");
}
```

};

Comment: Thank you, but by previous iteration do you mean ``sum``?